# Problema ao enviar lista de datasource pra sub relatórios

Tags: java, ireport, jasper-reports

Estou com problemas em abrir um relatório com sub relatórios passando um datasource.

No Ireport executo o relatorio com sub relatórios normalmente, mas o relatório principal está com uma conexão com o banco e esta conexão é passada para os sub relatórios e cada um dos relatórios tem sua query no banco.

Isso gera uma dúvida: quando é passado uma lista para o relatório a query SQL no relatório é desnecessária?

A aplicação para chamar o relatório passa um datasource só que somente o relatório principal recebe os dados da lista e não repassa para os sub relatórios.

ex: no relatório principal tem um campo localidade então escolho este item na lista, no próximo sub relatório tem um campo fornecedor então a lista vinda do relatório principal é recebida e escolho o item nomeFornecedor e no outro sub relatório tem o movimento com a maior parte da massa de dados da lista onde é preenchida as colunas.

nas propriedades do sub relatório em Connection type tenho que colocar : Use a datasource expression e em Connection expression: ´"new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista)"´.

Os exemplos que encontro seta a lista em um campo do relatório. E no meu caso quero que a lista chegue nos sub relatórios e cada item da lista preencha um campo do relatório.

Segue a imagem do layout de como estou fazendo o relatório: o principal traz as localidades o do meio traz os fornecedores daquela localidade e o último traz o movimento de acordo com o fornecedor e a localidade.

[image: Relatório]

Tentei também fazer isso em apenas um relatório com Grupos mas não consegui fazer com que trouxesse todos fornecedores de uma localidade e todas os movimentos relacionados co fornecedor e a localidade. Quem tiver alguma ideia de como chamar o relatório com está na figura pelo Sistema eu agradeço. Só um detalhe o sistema é WEB JSF + JPA + Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Se não houver uma quantidade de dados muito grande, de forma que não haja dificuldades em armazenar toda a lista em memória, você pode passar uma coleção qualquer de objetos para o relatório através do [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html).

Como você já tem os dados, o relatório não precisa executar nenhuma query. Os *fields* usados no relatório são os atributos dos objetos contidos na lista.

Para criar sub-relatórios dessa forma, faça com que os objetos da lista principal tenham um atributo que retorne uma outra lista e passe essa lista para os sub-relatórios.

Por exemplo, se você tiver isso:

```java
public class Fornecedor {
    private String contrato;
    ...
}
public class Localidade {
    private String descricao;
    public List<Fornecedor> fornecedores;
    ...
}
```

Primeiro, passe a lista de localidades para o relatório principal, então especifique como `DataSource` do subrelatório o seguinte:

```java
 new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{fornecedores})
```

Comment: A lista passada é da tabela movimento que tem relacionamentos com várias tabelas N:1 como: serviço,localidade e contrato e esta tem relacionamento com fornecedor. E esta lista é filtrada pelo usuário por uma data inicial e uma data final. Na figura que postei no Ireport o 1º relatório buscar todos os fornecedores de uma localidade no 2º busca toda movimento de uma localidade e o 3º busca o movimento em si. Ao executar no Ireport traz os dados todos agrupados como na figura mas é feito por uma conexão com o banco.

Comment: O problema é fazer isso na aplicação que envia uma lista que são os dados de preenchimento do relatório.
A lista Não é atributo de nenhuma classe e sim irá enviar todos os dados para preenchimento do relatório.

Comment: O relatório principal recebe dados da lista mas os sub relatórios não.

Comment: @user17132 Você não pode criar as classes na estrutura necessária e fazer um pré-processamento dos dados para que ele fique na estrutura que melhor se adeque ao relatório?

Comment: utluiz, não entendi. dar para explicar melhor?